# How do I filter multiple fileds and values in elasticsearch using C# NEST HighLevel?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been reading through the docs and been trying to achieve a solution to filter results through multiple fields and columns, however I keep getting errors; malformed query.

I want to filter the result with exact equal values, such as the following:

```
is_active: true
category_id: [1,2,3,4]
brand: "addidas"
gender: "male"`enter code here`
```

To make it more clear what I intend to do, this is how I'd like it to run if it would be written in SQL:

```
SELECT .... WHERE 
is_active= 1 AND category_id IN(1,2,3,4) 
AND brand='addidas' AND gender='male'
```

How to write above SQL using C# NEST HighLevel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it with the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "term": {"is_active": true }},
        { "terms": {"category_id": [1, 2, 3, 4] }},
        { "term": {"brand": "adidas" }},
        { "term": {"gender": "male" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In NEST, it'd look like this:

```
var searchResults = this.Client.Search<XYZ>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Filter(
                bs => bs.Term(p => p.IsActive, "true"),
                bs => bs.Terms(p => p.CategoryId, [1, 2, 3, 4]),
                bs => bs.Term(p => p.Brand, "adidas"),
                bs => bs.Term(p => p.Gender, "male")
            )
        )
    )
);
```